# Accessing Ceph objects created through Object Gateway via filesystem

Tags: ceph

I'm trying to access objects created via the Object Gateway via the filesystem (Ceph Filesystem or Block Device). The Ceph [documentation](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/) mentions:

> Ceph Object Gateway can store data in the same Ceph Storage Cluster used to store data from Ceph Filesystem clients or Ceph Block Device clients.

Does this imply that I can access those objects outside of the S3/Swift APIs?

If so, is it possible to access that data using the credentials managed by the Object Gateway?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Documentation [here](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/hammer/architecture/) says:

> S3/Swift Objects and Store Cluster Objects Compared
>
> Ceph’s Object Storage uses the term object to describe the data it
>   stores. S3 and Swift objects are not the same as the objects that Ceph
>   writes to the Ceph Storage Cluster. Ceph Object Storage objects are
>   mapped to Ceph Storage Cluster objects. The S3 and Swift objects do
>   not necessarily correspond in a 1:1 manner with an object stored in
>   the storage cluster. It is possible for an S3 or Swift object to map
>   to multiple Ceph objects.

Since you don't have one to one mapping I guess even if it's possible it won't be any easy.

Answer (score 0):

For the base part of Ceph, consider it as a single hard drive, with 3 separate partitions, each with their own way to access the data in a given partition: one partition for each of CephFS, RBD, RGW.

Beyond that, you COULD look at the [RGW NFS interface](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/nfs/) as a way to expose Ceph RGW data directly to the filesystem.